# Пример Moxy с Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, moxy

Может быть кто-то разбирался с тем как работает Moxy с Fragment ? Помогите, пожалуйста! Уже с неделю развлекаюсь.
Не могу реализовать пример из этого видео от разработчиков Moxy https://youtu.be/8_hbxA4kx50?t=1048 .
При повороте экрана всё равно обнуляются счетчики.

View

```
public interface CounterView extends MvpView {
    @StateStrategyType(AddToEndStrategy.class)
    void showCount(int count);
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.frame_1, getFragment(0xffFF80AB))
                .add(R.id.frame_2, getFragment(0xffCCFF90))
                .commit();
    }

    private Fragment getFragment(int color){
        CounterFragment fragment = new CounterFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("argColor", color);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
public class CounterFragment extends MvpAppCompatFragment implements CounterView {
    @InjectPresenter
    CounterPresenter counterPresenter;

    TextView counterTextView;
    int color;

    @ProvidePresenter
    CounterPresenter    provideCounterPresenter(){
        color = (int) getArguments().get("argColor");
        return new CounterPresenter(color);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        this.getView().setBackgroundColor(counterPresenter.getColor());
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_counter, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        counterTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.counter_text);
        view.findViewById(R.id.plus_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counterPresenter.onPlusClick();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void showCount(int count) {
        counterTextView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    }
}
```

Presenter

```
@InjectViewState
public class CounterPresenter extends MvpPresenter<CounterView> {
    private int mCount;
    private int color;


    public CounterPresenter(int color){
        super();
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFirstViewAttach() {
        super.onFirstViewAttach();
        getViewState().showCount(mCount);
    }

    public void onPlusClick(){
        mCount++;
        getViewState().showCount(mCount);
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

Gradle

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'com.github.moxy-community:moxy:1.0.13'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.moxy-community:moxy-compiler:1.0.13'
    implementation 'com.github.moxy-community:moxy-androidx:1.0.13'
    implementation 'com.github.moxy-community:moxy-material:1.0.13'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ в документации по Moxy:
https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/wiki/CustomView-as-MvpView

Правда вместо фрагментов тут используют класс наследующийся от FrameLayout.
Но по сути наверное тоже самое.